# Why is there an error cannot find module @electron/remote/main when installing the application?

Tags: javascript

I am developing an application on Electron.js, for communication between the main process I use
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()

when I run an unbuilt application, everything works, but when I compile the project into an exe and run it, I get the error cannot find module @electron/remote/main, what should I do? (I use remote to minimize the window and generate a child window through js)

I try through ipcMain, it works, but then the application freezes (buttons do not respond)

[image]

Comment: Make sure that `@electron/remote/main` is in your package.json dependencies and not in devDependencies

Comment: Yes, I threw it in "dependencies" but it did not help
"dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "2.0.9"
  },

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it myself through experiments, mistakes and successes,
I realized that I don’t need to build applications in Electron Fiddle, I make a project, then before building I delete the entire node_modules folder, then I add the following to package.json:

```
{
   "name": "name",
   "productName": "name",
   "description": "blbla",
   "keywords": [],
   "main": "./main.js",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "author": "lala",
   "scripts": {
     "start": "electron .",
     "build-all": "electron-builder --ia32 --x64 -w && C: && dir/s",
     "build-win32": "electron-builder --ia32 -w",
     "build-win64": "electron-builder --x64 -w"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "@electron/remote": "2.0.9"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "electron-builder": "24.0.0-alpha.13",
     "electron": "22.1.0"
   }
 }
```

install: npm install --save @electron/remote
and then I run the commands for the assembly and then everything works